# Glob Pattern Matching String in either folder or file name

Tags: glob

I need to match the word "cache" in either a folder or filename, and it also has to end in .test.js

Example:

```
    /Users/doge/lib/cache/index.js // should not match
    /Users/doge/lib/cache/index.test.js // should match
    /Users/doge/lib/something/index.test.js // should not match
    /Users/doge/lib/something/cache.test.js // should match
```

I've tried `/**/*cache*.test.js` but that doens't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `**/{*cache*/*,*cache*}.test.js` ? This is assuming you are using minimatch library (which is likely if you are working with JavaScript). Try using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F%7B*cache*%2F*%2C*cache*%7D.test.js&f=%2FUsers%2Fdoge%2Flib%2Fcache%2Findex.js%2C%2FUsers%2Fdoge%2Flib%2Fcache%2Findex.test.js%2C%2FUsers%2Fdoge%2Flib%2Fsomething%2Findex.test.js%2C%2FUsers%2Fdoge%2Flib%2Fsomething%2Fcache.test.js) to test and improve your pattern.

In the pattern I mentioned `{}` are a feature called brace expansion. This pattern will be expanded into two separate patterns: one for matching a directory name and the other for matching filename `**/*cache*/*.test.js`, `**/*cache*.test.js`. This is still not perfect because the folder containing `cache` will have to be exactly one level above the file itself but maybe it works for you.

Comment: is there a way to do it recursively in all folders?

Comment: `**/*cache*.test.js` will already match all files that end in `.test.js` and have `cache` in the filename in all the directories and subdirectories. 

Matching the `cache` folder is the tricky part. So if you would like to match `/Users/doge/lib/cache/a/index.test.js` You would need `**/*cache*/**/*.test.js` but that will not match `/Users/doge/lib/cache/index.test.js`. So maybe a combination of three patterns `**/{*cache*/**/*,*cache*/*,*cache*}.test.js`.